# Data Sync with WCF

Tags: wcf, synchronization

Here is the scenario:

1. Client sends a request to WCF Server to get product list.
2. WCF Server retrieves product list and returns it to the Client.
3. Client saves product list into the client's database.
   (Client and WCF Server distributed in different location, connect through internet.)

Problem is: during step 3, Client maybe save product list unsuccessfully.

So, is there any good way to let WCF Server know if the Client has downloaded and saved the product list successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No server doesn't know about the final state of the action performed by the client. For server the operation ends when it returns response to the transport channel. It is up to you as client's developer to handle any exception and call the service again if needed.

Btw. did you check MS Sync Framework? It does exactly what you describes and it supports WCF.

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked the WCF distributed transaction, it seems good.

Comment: Distributed transaction can solve it as well but it makes sense only if server is performing some transactional operations (changes) after reading data. That is something you forgot to mention in your question.